# How to get the theoretic serial number of list elements if they were sorted by the sum in Python?

Tags: python, list, numpy, sorting, sortedlist

I have a list given filled with numpy arrays such as:

```
lst = [np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
       np.array([16, 17, 18, 19, 20]),
       np.array([6, 7, 8, 9, 10]),
       np.array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15])]
```

I have already tried sort and sorted functions, but I did not find the proper key to monitor serial numbers.

I would like to find out which place would the elements (numpy arrays) of the list take if I sorted them based on their sum.

Considering the example, my expected output would be:

```
output = [0, 3, 1, 2]
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you want to shuffle the array after sort or just want to print indexes ?

Comment: Can you tell us how you calculated the `output = [0, 3, 1, 2]`?

Comment: @AboAmmar I think his output are the index of sorting : 0 is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] the smaller one, 3 is [16, 17, 18, 19, 20] the bigger one etc...

Answer (score 3):

Update: For efficiency, you may want to call `np.argsort` only once. Then use the result as indices for the final output.

```
ind = np.argsort(np.sum(lst, 1))
output = ind[ind]
```

---

Use `np.argsort` twice on the sum of elements:

```
import numpy as np

lst = [np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
       np.array([16, 17, 18, 19, 20]),
       np.array([6, 7, 8, 9, 10]),
       np.array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15])]

print(np.argsort(np.argsort(np.sum(lst, 1))))
```

Output:

```
[0 3 1 2]
```

Comment: better use `scipy.stats.rankdata` to avoid the double `argsort` ;)

Comment: @mozway How much better is that?

Comment: @Kelly it supports many ranking methods and I think it's using indexing to reverse the sorted order so it might be more efficient on large input (I haven't checked the code recently though)

Comment: looks like with less than ~1K elements, the double argsort is faster (probably due to scipy overhead), then rankdata is faster (e.g. ~1.5x faster on 1M elements)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`scipy.stats.rankdata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html):

```
import numpy as np

lst = [np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
       np.array([16, 17, 18, 19, 20]),
       np.array([6, 7, 8, 9, 10]),
       np.array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15])]

from scipy.stats import rankdata
out = (rankdata(np.sum(lst, 1))-1).astype(int)

# array([0, 3, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think expected output should be `[0,2,3,1]`

You can use sorted

```
import numpy as np
list_ = [np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), np.array([16, 17, 18, 19, 20]), np.array([6, 7, 8, 9, 10]), np.array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15])]
print([i for i, _ in sorted(zip(range(len(list_)), list_), key=lambda x: sum(x[1]))])
```